# abort is not working with $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, server

I am using jquery. I write a script where user **A** create chatwindow/chatbox for chatting user **B**, when window opened `$.get` method start sending request to server for check new message. My code works perfectaverything...  but I want when user **A** close chatbox of user **B** then `$.get` shouldn't be send request to server.

Here is my `$.get` function that send request to server for check new request:

```
function getMessages(sender, receiver,receiverName, Clbk) {
    $.get('chat.php',
        { sender: sender, 
            receiver: receiver
        },
        function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
        if(response.success) {
            var html = '';
            var messages = response.messages;
            for(var m in messages) {
                var message = messages[m];
                var senderId = message.sender;
                var receiverId = message.receiver;
                var timestamp = message.timestamp;
                var body = message.body;
                //var msgId = message.msgId;
                html += '<p><b>'+((senderId == sender)?'ME':receiverName)+'</b>: '+body+'</p>';
            }

            $('.usermsg'+receiver).html(html);
        }

        if(Clbk) {
            //console.log(Clbk);
            Clbk();
        }

    });
}
```

When I call this function code(when user click on User **B** it start sending requests):

```
callback = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        getMessages(sender, user_id, username, callback);
    }, 3000);
};
getMessages(sender, user_id, username, callback);
```

This code is when user **A** close window for chatting User **B**:

```
**$('#windows').on('click','.cls', function(){
    **getMessages(sender, user_id, username, callback).abort;**
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});**
```

How can I stop sending request to the server?

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is not possible through jQuery (I don't think any of the languages will do). You cannot modify the behavior of other browser in some other computer.

Comment: Why are you trying to abort the ajax for B? Let it run. He won't get any messages... He can send but nothing will happen if he does.

Comment: load on server of these requests  ??

Comment: Just return something special from the server if user A leaves, then check for it, and abort the recursion with the timeout. Generally sockets is easier for chat apps.

Comment: that is not one problem only. if user **A** want to chatting with user **B** and **C**, my function will send request for only latest user not for both user. how can i solve it ?